# How to prevent buying an item at a special price unless specified number of other items are purchased?

Tags: cart, shopping

I've managed before to ensure customers purchase x amount of items at £y each to get a discount voucher of £z. However, I now have a large range of items which are already discounted as a special price (differing amounts, so coupon not the way forward here) and I'd like to know if there's a way to make sure customers can only buy it if they purchase, let's say, 3 other products. Any ideas anyone please?

Comment: you can use "shopping cart price rules"  get help here : http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/25-magento-shopping-cart-price-rules/

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to set up bundle or a grouped products for that.